# Debugging console input using NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Is there a way in NetBeans that while you are debugging a Java program to modify or check the value that a function or variable returns. The same way you can use the console in Matlab.

I'm not speaking about the usual debugging tools variable windows etc.

Example I want to break at a method in car class and input

```
>car.getMileage()
```

and get..

```
>car.getMileage()
>2500
```

or

```
>car.setMileage(100)
>car.getMileage()
>100
```

Comment: Other than doing `System.out.println(...);` at that moment?

Comment: Yeah, I want it dynamic.

Comment: @user758114 try a [`Logger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) or a debugger.

Comment: Java is not entirely an interpreted language so this probably doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Netbeans there is a tab under your source code window (there by default I think) called Variables. In that window you can edit the Value field of any variable that is in scope while suspended at a breakpoint. This value should update for the java application as you change it in real time. You can invoke methods the same way, by adding a watch. Like say you had a static method getInt(); which returns some value. Just make a watch for getInt(), and the Value column will show you the return value. So for your example, make a watch for car.setMileage(100) after your breakpoint is hit. The value column will likely be 'void'. Then make another watch for car.getMileage(). 100 should be returned.

Comment: +1 I use it as well. But general demand is in a more convenient way - like Chrome Javascript Console. Netbeans Console unfortunately allows typing, not code execution.

Answer (score 1):

Use an IDE such as Eclipse. You can set breakpoints, set statements and execute them. This is a feature of most modern IDEs actually.

More info on the display view can be found here : http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-debug_view.htm

For a nice overview of the debugging features of Eclipse, check out this post : http://www.cavdar.net/2008/09/13/5-tips-for-debugging-java-code-in-eclipse/